# Enterprise reCaptcha with image selection challenge

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We have implemented google enterprise reCaptcha, which is score based decision making. But we are looking for enterprise recaptcha, with image selection challenge popup.
Please let us know , is it possible, or only score or checkbox based captcha possible with enterprise account?
Code is as below:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=<site_key>
```

To Execute Recaptcha:

```
public executeEnterpriseCaptcha(){
       
        (window as any).grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(environment.captchaSiteKeyEntpr, {action: 'CONTACTUS'}).then((token) => {
             this.contactUsFun(token);
        });
    }
```

The above requirement is possible to do with V2 version, but i am looking for with enterprise one, I have checked the Documentation for enterprise captcha, could not find anything related to image based challenge.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T50bq.jpg)
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq

Thanks in advance guys for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only 2 options when it comes to reCaptcha enterprise:

- score challenge (this will never show the image selection challenge)
- checkbox challenge (this will sometime show the image selection challenge if they think the user might be a robot)

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/choose-key-type

If you want your users to be prompted with an image challenge, you can implement a checkbox challenge on your site.  In the enterprise dashboard, you can then increase the Challenge security to the highest level:

[image: reCaptcha difficulty]

This way, every time Google thinks there's a slight chance the user interacting with your site is a robot, it will automatically display the image selection challenge.  It won't pop up every time though.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolasome, for enriching with your insight. It is helpful to proceed.